# Linq group with min date and count on join

Tags: linq

I am trying to set PastEvents, a int, and need some guidance in how to get the final, EventCount converted to an int.  I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'int'".  I am thinking of using Sum() or FirstorDefault().  Any help would be appreciated.

```
PastEvents = from ev in
             (from ev in
                 ((from e in db.ActivityEventEntities
                   join d in db.ActivityEventDateEntities on e.EventID equals d.EventID
                   where e.ActivityID == 58
                   group new { e, d } by new
                   {
                     e.EventID
                     } into g
                     select new
                      {
                          EventID = (Int32?)g.Key.EventID,
                          StartDate = (DateTime?)g.Min(p => p.d.DateValue)
                                                   }))
                                          where
                                            ev.StartDate > DateTime.Now
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              Dummy = "x"
                                          })
                                     group ev by new { ev.Dummy } into g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         EventCount = (Int64?)g.Count()
                                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select new
{
    EventCount = (Int64?)g.Count()
}.First().EventCount;
```

Comment: I ended up having to use FirstorDefault but this worked.  Thanks.